# Using GridBagConstraint.anchor = NORTH for two elements

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I want to set two elements in a GridBagLayout on top of each other and both shall be at the top of the layout (the second element shall start on the bottom of the first element).

Furthermore shall the second element fill the space down to the bottom.

The `gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraint.NORTH` works for the first element but the second element will not stick to the top of the free space.
Instead it sticks to the top of the second half of the layout.

[image: screenshot]

That's my code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class TestFrame extends JFrame{

    public TestFrame(){
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;

        JPanel one = new JPanel();
        one.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
        one.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));

        JPanel two = new JPanel();
        two.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
        two.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));

        this.add(one, gbc);

        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;

        this.add(two, gbc);

        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new TestFrame();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution:
If I set `wheighty` of the first element to `0.0` and only the `weighty` of the second element to `1.0` it works as planned.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class TestFrame extends JFrame{

    public TestFrame(){
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        gbc.weighty = 0.0;

        JPanel one = new JPanel();
        one.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
        one.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));

        JPanel two = new JPanel();
        two.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
        two.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));

        this.add(one, gbc);

        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 0.0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;

        this.add(two, gbc);

        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new TestFrame();
    }
}
```